# Why doesn't a query on data.stackexchange.com show the most recent data?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I have [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/501254) query:

```
SELECT * from Posts
WHERE OwnerUserId = 2545680
```

I've used my OwnerUserId. Why doesn't it show the most recent questions I asked?

Comment: Oh, because it's updated once a week. Something wrong with this recent flood of questions about the lack of the info.

Comment: thanks, is there any other way to see questions for the last few days sorted by votes?

Comment: Since it's a dupe, the thing you're asking about is a separate question...

Comment: @nicael did you choose a question in random?? Because it can't be less fit as dupe. Fixed with hammer, but just curious.

Comment: @Maximus not using SEDE. But you got the built-in search mechanism, in your case what you want is [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a2545680%20is%3aq). You can change the `is:q` to `is:a` for answers, and add search terms. Note the sort by active instead of by relevance as well.